# AWS EMR - Write to S3 Using the Correct Encryption Key

Tags: encryption, pyspark, emr, amazon-emr, amazon-kms

I have an EMR cluster (v5.12.1) and my S3 bucket setup with encryption at rest using the same AWS SSE-KMS key.

Reading the data from S3 works fine, but when I write to my S3 bucket using a Pyspark script - the parquet files are encrypted using the default 'aws/s3' key.

How can I get Spark to use the correct KMS key?

The cluster has Hadoop 2.8.3 and Spark 2.2.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to not use s3a:// or s3n:// paths for your output files.

The files will be written to S3 and encrypted with the correct SSE-KMS key if you use the s3:// prefix only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CMK make sure you are using that while creating the EMR cluster under configuration section:

```
{
    "Classification": "emrfs-site",
    "Properties": {
                   "fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption": "true",
                   "fs.s3.serverSideEncryption.kms.keyId": "<YOUR_CMK>"
                  }
}
```